# Cannot find module error when archiving iOS project using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I get an error "cannot find module SwiftMessages" when archiving an iOS project. I'm using CocoaPods, Xcode V10.2, and iOS V10.1. Here's my pod file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.1'

      # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
      use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Minuteapp
  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FacebookShare'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'FolioReaderKit'
  pod 'SwiftyStoreKit'
  pod 'SwiftMessages' , '7.0.0'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'Promises' 
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK' #Analytics Pod
  pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryAds' #Advertising Pod (requires Analytics)
  pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryMessaging'
  pod 'STPopup' 
  pod 'SendGrid-Swift'
  pod 'DeviceKit'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the `DerivedData` folder:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

There is a folder inside named `ModuleCache` that caches module versions. Removing it will make all the modules be recompiled, probably solving your issue.